# JSON string passed from frontend with AJAX POST to Django view results in strange characters added

Tags: json, django, ajax

I am trying to pass a GeoJson with AJAX call to backend. I printed to console before sending the whole string and no error was there. Printing in the view the request.POST shown this error. The error occurred on the 'streetWeb' variable. This variale comes from a textfile. Its content comes from a GeoJson stringified.

**The call**

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $('#confImp').data('url'),
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
        data: { "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrftoken, 'streetWeb': toExpwe, 'int_points': toExpip},
        success: function(res){
            .........
        }
    })
```

This error occurs a couple of times always identical.
The following image shows the error I got.

[image: This is a portion of the error log showing the characters added.]

Answer (score 0):

Send data in json format

```
 $.ajax({
    url: $('#confImp').data('url'),
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrftoken, 'streetWeb': toExpwe, 'int_points': toExpip})
    success: function (data) {                
    }           
});
```

Comment: Well, if I send it in json format, I got a problem with the csfrtoken which is missing (I'm using docker)