# how to solve problem with AJAX requests in django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

script.js:

```
console.log('work')
const url = window.location.href

const searchForm = document.getElementById('search-form')
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search-input')
const resultsBox = document.getElementById('results-box')

const csrf = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value

 console.log('first module success')
const sendSearchData = (product)=>{
    $.ajax({
        type: ' POST',
        url: 'search/',
        data: {
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrf,
            'product': product,
        },
        success: (res)=>{
            console.log('---res ---', res)
        },
        error:(err)=>{
            console.log('---error---',err)
        }
    })

}

searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', e=>{
    console.log(e.target.value)

    if (resultsBox.classList.contains('not-visible')){
        resultsBox.classList.remove('not-visible')
    }
    if (e.target.value == '') {
        resultsBox.classList.add('not-visible')
    }
    sendSearchData(e.target.value)
})
```

views.py:

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'shop/home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):


        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()


            if self.request.headers.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
            product = self.request.POST.get('product')
            return context, JsonResponse({'data':product})


        return context
```

after entering something into the search bar, this code is activated and sends Ajax requests that pass this text, but I get an error in the console

> statusText: "SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified"

Comment: 'product': product,   try remove the comma after product

Comment: @Jisson, ok.
but it does not solve the problem

Comment: I guess the issue you got in the django side, please share the stack trace too

Comment: dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
 data: JSON.stringify({'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrf,'product': product})

Comment: add the above to the ajax request and make use JSON.stringify

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75554108/json-string-passed-from-frontend-with-ajax-post-to-django-view-results-in-strang/75554988#75554988